# How to add top or bottom border to UiView in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

[image]

The border in above is what i want to achieve.

Comment: How do you think this is done?, do you have any code? did you try?

Comment: Well i did try a library called UIVIew+Borders but it didnot worked as expected.

Comment: you can simply take another UIView with height 1 and width equal to parent view. or you can achieve it by bezier path.

Comment: ok Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
-(void)addBottomBorderToView:(UIView *)view{
    UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,view.frame.size.height - 1, view.frame.size.width, 1)];
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor;
    [view addSubview:bottomBorder];
}
```

Swift :

```
func addBottomView(view : UIView){
    let bottomView = CGRect(0,view.frame.size.height-1,view.frame.size.width,1)
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor
    view.addSubView(bottomView)
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with my answer ? why is it marked negative ?

Comment: what about top border

Comment: same as above just change this line: 
let bottomView = CGRect(0,view.frame.size.height-1,view.frame.size.width,1)

to this :
let bottomView = CGRect(0,1,view.frame.size.width,1)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet